# Dois servidores JBoss. Inicia e o outro não. Mesma configuração

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jboss

Tenho dois servidores que rodam o JBoss com os mesmos parâmetros para a mesma aplicação. Apesar do log informar claramente o erro, não entendo porque num servidor funciona e no outro não. Ele inicia sem problemas, define os beans, porém quando chega a esse ponto:

```
16:17:42,558 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a7ba05: defining beans
```

Ele destrói a todos e volta a defini-los, após emitir a mensagem:

```
root of factory hierarchy
```

Ele fecha os serviços:

```
16:17:42,643 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
16:17:42,644 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] (MSC service thread 1-2) closing
16:17:42,645 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-2) Shutting down ExecutorService 'myScheduler'
16:17:42,645 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] (MSC service thread 1-2) Shutting down ExecutorService
```

E passa a emitir os erros de criação de beans (exemplo de um deles):

```
16:17:42,646 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'controleAcaoDisciplinarServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

E no final:

```
Error creating bean with name 'turmaServiceImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?;
```

Um problema no .war está descartado, pois executo o mesmo em outros 3 servidores diferentes e sem problemas.

Lembrando que utilizo as mesmas configurações para toda a infraestrutura nos outros servidores. Fiz um teste também utilizando o mesmo banco de dados e continua a mesma situação.

Tô enrolado. Alguma ideia? Please, help me!

Comment: Os dois servidores estão apenas com o WAR desta aplicação ou existem outras aplicações nestes 2 servidores com Jboss?

Comment: Sim, apenas com o WAR desta aplicação.

Comment: Quando você diz 2 servidores são 2 servidores diferentes ou duas INSTÂNCIAS do mesmo servidor diferentes?